# How to assign object to an empty array

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular6 application,

I have declared empty array as below:

```
conversation=[]
```

and I have constructor in shared module where it does initialize the object of conversation below is the code

```
export class messageThread {
    internalId?: number;
    unreadMessageCount?: number;
    subject?: string;
    managerCode?: string;
    constructor(json?: any) {
        if ( !json ) return;
        this.internalId= json.internalId || 0;
        this.unreadMessageCount=json.internalId || 0;;
        this.subject = json.internalId || '';
        this.managerCode =json.managerCode|| '';

    }
}
```

However when in my ts file if I do like below.

```
this.conversation = new dataModel.messageThread ();
```

it gives me error: saying that only push, pop can be used, I know that this is because I have initialized it with empty array and it does expect array as an assignment, is there any way we can assign object to an empty array or I am missing something here

Comment: What kind of an array are you expecting to get as a result? an array of MessageThreads? if so then just `push` to the conversation the new Object.

Comment: Why you assign object to the array. If you have only one object then array is of no use and if you have multiple objects then you have to push in Array. Any specific reason you are assigning object to array?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want typed array:

```
public conversation: messageThread [] = [];
```

And to push values:

```
this.conversation.push(new dataModel.messageThread());
```

Answer (score 1):

while working on angular alway keep in mind that angular is javascript framework so you can use any javascript function in angular as per you question you can simplly use .push() function on your array;

```js
 var abc = [];
    obj = {itemName:'paste',itemPrice: '50$'};
    
    abc.push(obj);
    
    
    console.log(abc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use object de-structuring like this...

```
conversation=[];
obj = {
  itemName:'paste',
  itemPrice: '50$'
}

ngOnInit(){
   this.conversation = [ { ...this.obj } ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to assign an object to an Array type. If you want to assing the object to `conversation` variable. Why don't you put the type of `conversation` or assign it like an empty object. `conversation = {}` and then make it Equals to this `this.conversation = new dataModel.messageThread ();`.